# Google Looker - Alert Queries

Tags: looker

I am currently setting up alerts for our looker dashboard to email my team when a metric hits a certain trigger. I set up the alerts to query every 15 minutes, however, one issue I am facing is that regardless if a dashboard is refreshed, the alert will always grab data from the cache.

I believe this is due to the default 1 hour persist length, but does anyone have a solution on having my alert query FRESH data from the database and not from the cache? The screenshot shows that the alert queries grab data at the same source time throughout the hour, but I expect them to query items straight from the database.

Does anyone have a solution **without** changing the explore/model persist time?[image: Alert queries]